# How to remove unwanted transparency for object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I have drawn this deer and I want it to be in solid color, But it is transparent, though the opacity is 100%.

what is wrong with this deer.

please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Need to see the **Appearance Panel** with the deer selected and all fills/strokes expanded. It would appear that you *possibly* have some appearance settings for the *group*.

Comment: @Scott there is 12% opacity in APPEARANCE PANEL!! how does that happen? how can I fix it?

Comment: I can fix it, I have increased the opacity. Thank you so much @Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the **Appearance Panel**. That will tell you *everything* about the selected object and where, if anywhere, transparency is being introduced.

If you see anything in the Appearance Panel set to less than 100% opacity, merely correct it.

It would appear as though you have some appearance settings applied at the **Group** level. This is indicated by the solid circles (often called a "meatball") to the right on the Layer's panel ...

[image]

Using the Appearance Panel is often quicker because it shows *all* possible areas where opacity can be adjusted as opposed to other panels which show only specific areas.

---

How it happens.. hard to say. Could be that you drew something, reduced the opacity, then drew something else and the opacity doesn't reset between objects unless you tell it to. Or you had a low opacity object and used a Pathfinder command to combine it with some other object(s) and the transparent object was on top. Just guessing though.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem `:)` Glad to help.